# How to Access WiFi functionality in ionic 2 Framework

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I want to use WiFi functionality in `ionic 2`. I tried to access the node library `node-WiFi` but it gives me a `child process error`.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some `Nodejs` libraries are not supported in `angular 2`. If you want to access the WiFi in the `ionic 2` framework then you will need Cordova plugins. To access WiFi function, Cordova has a plugin named `Cordova-plugin-hotspot`. Install it globally and you will be able to access the functions.

Comment: ohh ok i will try it